# Append text input in the the text box to the url and open the url link

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "www.google.com/search/" + userInput;
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
}


</script>

Here is a link : <a href="" id=lnk>nothing here yet</a> <br>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value=' ' />
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Change Link'/>
```

So, this basically does the following:

User enters a word in the text box, and that word is appended at the end of the link given (www.google.com/search/). And the link is displayed above on the page.

But instead of displaying the link on the page, I want it to open that page when the button is clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: In your first <a> tag, the id should be enclosed in quotation marks id="lnk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/gk52ou0m/)

Try `window.location`  to redirect to the page on click.

That is, in your code try like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "www.google.com/search/" + userInput;
    window.location = "www.google.com/search/" + userInput;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lal but after I click the button then it does redirect to the new link but it also displays that link on the page for a second. How can I avoid that?

Comment: See my edited script. Remove `lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;`.

Comment: Is it possible to make it work by pressing the 'enter' button also?

Comment: Try changing the input type to submit.

Comment: was you trying that in the above fiddle ?

Comment: which fiddle are you talking about? I tried that in the code after updating it with whatever was told here.

Comment: Ok..see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/gk52ou0m/2/).. added code for enter key.

Comment: Cool! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current url by changing `window.location`

This would make your function look as follows:

```
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "www.google.com/search/" + userInput;
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
    window.location = lnk.href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others, you can use the location object in two ways

[Replacing it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

```
window.location.replace("http://url.to")
```

or setting the href value

```
window.location.href = "http://url.to"
```

You also need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the text input to make it url safe

```
window.location.href = "http://url.to/search?q="+encodeURIComponent("Query value")
```

Also, it's important to include the protocol (http) if you are linking to an external domain.