# user inputs variable from form that is used in redirct url

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a page (in wordpress) and I want to redirect a user to a specific url based on the input they make in a form.

EG. I want them to input a simple text string - such as '4BBQWER' into a form

and when submitted they are redirected to https://example.com/single-submission-trackback/?id=**4BBQWER**

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Change the form's method to `GET` instead of `POST` ? Where's your form code my dude

Comment: If the form has just that one field, you can simply use the GET method to send the form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it should work for you:

html:

```
Here is a link : <a href="" id=lnk>nothing here yet</a> <br>
```

js:

```
function changeText2(){
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
lnk.href = "www.google.com/search/" + userInput;
lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gk52ou0m/27/

This was answered on a different question. (number [32231616](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231616/append-text-input-in-the-the-text-box-to-the-url-and-open-the-url-link))